# Store return values from python function

Tags: python-3.6

I have a function that provides the sample space for the coin toss, I need to store a file with the results (return), but I'm not getting it. my function is:

```
def space(flips, n):
    if n == 0:
        print (flips)
        return

    space(flips +"H,", n-1)
    space(flips +"T,", n-1)



res=space("",6)
```

I try with python script.py > out.txt, but the archive file is incomplete.
the font of code is: https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/2009519/how-to-print-the-sample-space-of-an-experiment-in-python

Thanks a lot, I'm new to Python

Comment: I didn't understand what you are asking.  File is ok, what about space().  Can i know space() is for what.

Comment: When you do `python script.py > out.txt`,  contents of print() are written.

Comment: can you disclose,  what type of data want to get as output.

Comment: you are passing *6* for spaces,  but in space() the condition is **if n == 0**, so here the **print(flips)** never be executed till **n == 0**,

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
I will try explain the problem, for example, when I do space("",4) the function return 16 possibilities (x^n), where x= possibilities (H or T) and n= the numbers of coins:
H,H,H,H – H,H,H,T…etc.
So, if I add more possibilities to x, for example for a “dice” (x=6) and the number of "dice" is n=5, I have 6^5=7776 combinations, when I do python script.py > out.txt. The archive (out.txt) does not contain all the information (possibilities).